# android metaio no valid license provided

Tags: android, metaio

i try to create augmented reality app with metaio sdk.i have one problem.i can not register my app in metaio web site.i try to register my app  [in](http://my.metaio.com/)

I received an email with my new signature via email so in the metaioSDK project I changed in /res/values/string.xml the value metaioSDKSignature with my new signature.

So,I build my new apk and install it in my phone but when I press the button it show me the following message
[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to login  into your account and folow the process of app registration in myApps(https://mobiledeveloperportal.ar-live.de/index.php?state=portal) tab. Once you are done with this you should be able to run your app.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if your license is according with your specific android target version, Application Name(the name that you register in the web site) needs to match with the app name, or you can try catching the Metaio debug exception when string signature fails.

Comment: You need to login  into your account and folow the process of app registration in myApps tab. Once you are done with this you should be able to run your app.